# Joomla installation SQLSRV

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, joomla, sqlsrv

System config: WAMP

SQL Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) (Service Pack 3)

Unable to install JOOMAL With SQLSRV

```
You need SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.1600.1) or higher to continue the installation. Your version is: 10.50.1600
```

The problem solved with below code change.

**Script Path:**

> libraries\joomla\database\driver\sqlsrv.php  ==> for 3.0
>   libraries\joomla\database\database\sqlsrv.php ==> 2.5.11

```
   protected $dbMinimum = '10.50.1600';
```

please share your experience/advise to fix this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to install SQLSRV or it's already working but Joomla fails to recognise it?

Comment: Please do *NOT* modify core files.  Hacking the core can cause issues down the road.  With that said, I'd suggest doing a var_dump in the getVersion() method of that sqlsrv.php file after `$version = sqlsrv_server_info($this->connection);` is called to see if the PHP connection is getting the right version.  If it isn't, then there's an issue outside of Joomla which needs to be resolved.

Comment: @ Álvaro G. Vicario: i am newly installing joomla with  SQLSRV